# Android Studio unable to recognize newly created resource value files (res/layout)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I recently started learning Android Studio in Kotlin and am facing this really dumb issue. So, when I try to create a new resource value file under the res/layout folder, I can't for some reason add it to my Activity files such as MainActivity.kt. The reason for it is because it doesn't recognize any changes in the directory. I honestly don't know why this issue is occuring. I followed a tutorial on GitHub (https://github.com/smartherd/MsgShareApp/tree/section_two_video_three) and I have the exact same file structure and pretty much the same code as him, but mine is unable to recognize changes in the layout directory.

Here's an image of the error (SecondActivity.kt): 
[image]

Here's an image of the directory : 
[image]

Here's an image of activity_second.xml file:
[image]
Auto syntax highlighting doesn't show activity_second.xml resource file : 
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild project. Android studio can get bugged. Try to "Restart and invalidate caches" also

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!